# Cancel async workflow that executes blocking synchronous work

Tags: .net, f#

Im not sure that it's possible to do this, but I have an async workflow that executes a blocking operation. And I would like to cancel it if it has run for a long period of time, including the thread that is currently executing the workflow.

Here is my testcase:

```
let counter = ref 0
let work = async {
    let computation = async {
        System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(counter) |> ignore
        let blockingWork = Async.Sleep(2000) |> Async.RunSynchronously
        System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(counter) |> ignore
    }
    do! computation
}

use cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource(1000)
let tryCancelled = Async.TryCancelled(work, fun _ -> printf "Cancelled")
do Async.Start(tryCancelled, cts.Token) 
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000) //Simulate other work
counter.contents |> should equal 1
```

The thing is that the workflow is successfully cancelled and the compensation function is called, but the computation continues and increments the counter...

Comment: the cancellation-support inside async basically works if you call other asyncs with `do!`, `let!` and some constructs like `while` - it will not interrupt sync. calls! So you either have to pass the Token on to the sync. block and check there if it got canceled or you have to do some gymnasitcs with Threads and Abort (**not recommended**!) - btw: this assumes that the Sleep is only for demonstration - if not you got a answer ;)

Comment: also: you did not cancel the token in your example - which of course also causes your assumption to be void ;)

Comment: @Carsten Ok I think I understand... And my fear is that I need to abort the thread somehow because the sync-work that I need to execute could potentially take a lot of time and its calling into an external lib that I have no control over...

Comment: honestly this is a no-go in most case as you have no control whatsoever if the code you *killed* is in any graceful state - but *if you really feel you have to* - you can subscribe to the tokens-event and kill the thread you created from there ... but again **not recommended** (also make sure to unsubscribe ... I saw nasty memory-leaks straight from this)

Comment: Sure, but what is better? To let the thread continue executing and take up a spot on the threadpool, or to kill it? I have other issues connected to the computation since it executes in a transcation scope which causes orphaned connections. But I can dispose the transaction with the cancellation, but the thread continues.

Comment: there is no way I can answer this for you - to be honest you should not get into a situation where you have to abort a thread no matter what - I would suggest looking for a way to break the computation down or to make it aware of the cancellation token

Answer (score 1):

Do the blockingWork in the async context with do! blockingWork

```
let counter = ref 0
let work = async {
    let computation = async {
        System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(counter) |> ignore
        let blockingWork = Async.Sleep(2000) 
        do! blockingWork 
        System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(counter) |> ignore
    }
    do! computation
}

let doit() =
    use cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource(1000)
    let tryCancelled = Async.TryCancelled(work, fun _ -> printf "Cancelled")
    do Async.Start(tryCancelled, cts.Token) 
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000) //Simulate other work
    counter.contents // |> should equal 1

doit()
```

Comment: Yes, Async.Sleep is used for demonstration. You could change it to Thread.Sleep() and skip the pipe to Async.RunSynchronously